# What are the thick red cylinders in 80104?

Tags: part-identification

What are the thick red cylinders with handles (not the drumsticks) that two minifigs are holding in set 80104 supposed to represent?
[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Michael has answered what pieces it is, but you ask what they represent, so I'm going to offer a guess at that: Fireworks.

Comment: I suppose that I indeed misread the OPs question. Still I think it's perfectly possible that someone unfamiliar with Technic lego wants to know more about the cilinders in this set, so I'm leaving my answer as is.

Comment: Indeed, the [description of the set on LEGO.com](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/product/lion-dance-80104) calls this out: "Accessory elements such [...] a rocket firework inspire unlimited play".

Comment: Apparently they're called [skyrockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyrocket).

Answer (score 16):

Those are red technic pin connectors

[image: pin connector]

[bricklick pin connector](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62462#T=S&C=5&O=%22color%22:%225%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

A "flick missile" pin is inserted which is one one side a bar so the minifig can hold it and on the other side a stud so the pyramid element can be placed on top.

[bricklink flick missile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=77562)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Great description of the parts, but I'll have to accept Henrik's answer as I asked what they represented.

Comment: yes, i understand